# How to Get user input in jQuery and use in the same?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get user input and process that input in same jQuery. How can I do that?

Say for example, I have a ball bouncing animation in jQuery, I want to ask the user how many times that ball has to bounce and based on his/her input, the ball has to bounce. How can I accomplish that? I know how to get values, but I don't know how to process the value.

For getting value I use:

```
$("button:#Get").click(function () {

$('input:number').val();

});
```

here is an example im trying to use the function,

```js
$(function() {
    
    var time = 500;
    var bounces = 20;
    var top_bounce = 10;
    
    function bounceDown(){
      $("#ball").animate({left:10, top: bounces*10}, time, function(){
        bounceUp();
      });
    };
    
    
    
    function bounceUp() {
      $("#ball").animate({top: top_bounce}, time);
      top_bounce = top_bounce + 10;
    };
    
    function shadowUp(){
      $("#shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 5, left: 10, top: bounces*15, opacity: 1}, time,    
    function(){
        shadowDown();
      });
    };
    
    function shadowDown() {
      $("#shadow").animate({width: 0, height: 0, left: 15, top: bounces*15, opacity: 0}, time);
    };     
    
    function finalDown(){
        $("#ball").animate({left:10, top: bounces*10}, time);
    };
    
    function finalShadow(){
    $("#shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 5, left: 10, top: bounces*15, opacity: 1}, time);    
    };
    
    $('#Get').click(function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < bounces; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
          bounceDown();
          shadowUp();      
        }, time*2*i);
        setTimeout(function(){
          finalDown();
          finalShadow();
      }, bounces*1000);
      };               
    });
    
    
    
});
```

```css
body {
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            width: 500px;
            height: 600px;
        }

        #ball {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #e65454;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

#shadow {
            position: absolute;
            height: 5px;
            width: 100px;
  bottom:0;
            background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(91,91,91,1) 0%,rgba(142,142,142,0.84) 16%,rgba(227,228,229,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5b5b5b', endColorstr='#00e3e4e5',GradientType=1 ); 
  opacity:0;
   }

div.inp{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:35px;
  left:30%;
  width:100%;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #e65454;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline:0;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
  outline:0;
  border: 2px solid #e65454;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #e65454;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="inp">
<input type="number" value="How Many Bounces?"></input>
<button id="Get">Set</button>
<button id="Reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
        <div id="ball"></div>
        <div id="shadow"></div>
    </div>
```

now i want ask user for the value and based on the value, "bounces" should updated in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function instead of anonymous function.

```
$(function() {
    //function body
}
```

define like

```
function bounce(){
    //function body
}
```

you can also pass the variable that determines the no. of bounces of ball, 'bounces' in your case.

```
function bounce(var bounces){
    //function body
    //write everything that you have written in your function except var bounces
    //as it is taken from input
}
```

Then you can call the above function in your onClick method. Also as said by @Franco you are using incorrect selector. so you can write something like

```
<input type="number" id="number" value="How Many Bounces?"></input>
```

Following will be your final js

```js
$("#Get").click(function () {
   bounces = $('#number').val();
   bounce(bounces);
 });

function bounce(bounces) {
    
    var time = 500;
    var top_bounce = 10;
  
 
    
    function bounceDown(){
      $("#ball").animate({left:10, top: bounces*10}, time, function(){
        bounceUp();
      });
    };
    
    
    
    function bounceUp() {
      $("#ball").animate({top: top_bounce}, time);
      top_bounce = top_bounce + 10;
    };
    
    function shadowUp(){
      $("#shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 5, left: 10, top: bounces*15, opacity: 1}, time,    
    function(){
        shadowDown();
      });
    };
    
    function shadowDown() {
      $("#shadow").animate({width: 0, height: 0, left: 15, top: bounces*15, opacity: 0}, time);
    };     
    
    function finalDown(){
        $("#ball").animate({left:10, top: bounces*10}, time);
    };
    
    function finalShadow(){
    $("#shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 5, left: 10, top: bounces*15, opacity: 1}, time);    
    };
    
    
      for (var i = 0; i < bounces; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
          bounceDown();
          shadowUp();      
        }, time*2*i);
        setTimeout(function(){
          finalDown();
          finalShadow();
      }, bounces*1000);
      };               
    
    
    
    
};
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: hi thank you so much for the answer. but i couldnt make it work. as i have Get clicked to animate it too.. can you show me how to get value after clicking set, and with that value, make the animation complete? here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/emjimadhu/pen/pEaxaz?editors=0010)

Comment: @EmJiMadhu edited the answer to include the correct js..mark the answer if you find it useful

Comment: thank you soooo much.. thanks a lot.. it works.. but only problem is i have click set button twice..! if its just one click it will be awesome..! but anyways thank you soooo much..!

Comment: @EmJiMadhu Actually I didn't read your complete code properly..now edited again...try it..it should work now..

Comment: hi again.. first aof all thank you so much for your answer, it helped me well, now im having bit sample problem, is it okay can you clear that? as you can see in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/emjimadhu/pen/pEaxaz) if you enter the value of 5, the ball stays on the floor at 4th and after few seconds the fifth bounce goes up and stays ther.. what is the problem here? i want to make that ball stay on floor on fifth count..! how to aceihve this? thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an invalid selector you need to do:

```
<input type="number" id="number" value="How Many Bounces?"></input>

$("button#Get").on('click',function () {
   var number = $('#number).val()
   console.log(number);
});
```